# Run downloaded SaltStack formula

Tags: salt-stack

I've downloaded the PHP formula by following the instructions here: https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/development/conventions/formulas.html

I've changed `apache` to `php`. In my salt config file (which I assume is `/etc/salt/master`), I've set `file_roots` like so:

```
file_roots:
  base:
    - /srv/salt
    - /srv/formulas/php-formula
```

I don't know how I'm supposed to run it now. I've successfully run a salt state file by discovering that the documentation is incomplete, so I'd missed a step I wasn't aware of.

If I try to run the formula the same way I've been running the state, I just get errors.

`salt '*' state.apply php-formula`

```
salt-minion:
    Data failed to compile:
----------
    No matching sls found for 'php-formula' in env 'base'
ERROR: Minions returned with non-zero exit code
```

I've also tried: `sudo salt '*' state.highstate`, and it also has errors:

```
salt-minion:
----------
          ID: states
    Function: no.None
      Result: False
     Comment: No Top file or master_tops data matches found.
     Changes:

Summary for salt-minion
------------
Succeeded: 0
Failed:    1
------------
Total states run:     1
Total run time:   0.000 ms
ERROR: Minions returned with non-zero exit code
```

Comment: Did you followed step 3 "Restart the Salt Master." after adding the lines to the master configuration?

Comment: @dahrens Yes, I've even restarted the whole machine and I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add a `top.sls` file to `/srv/salt/`, not just in `/srv/pillar/`. If you have a file called `/srv/salt/php.sls`, you have remove it, otherwise it will interfere with `/srv/pillar/php.sls`.

Contents of `/srv/salt/top.sls`:

```
base:
  '*':
    - php
```

This is kind of bizarre, because my previous test (which wasn't a formula) used `/srv/salt/php.sls` and `/srv/pillar/top.sls`. Now I'm using `/srv/pillar/php.sls` and `/srv/salt/top.sls`.

Comment: The reason is that `/srv/salt/php.sls` is derived by the formula. It is not just a file, but a whole folder. However - it results in `php` to be useable as a state. Salt merges together several sources into one state tree - which **is not** just a folder. Pillar is something different, but uses the same approach (without the merge - here it is one folder!). You may call `/srv/pillar/php.sls` completely different as long as you assign it to your minion using the `/srv/salt/top.sls` file. Usually they are called the same - but this might be confusing - especially when you are new to all this.

Comment: @dahrens I know what you mean by a directory structure; they talk about `file_roots` as if it's a file. It took a lot of searching to find it was a key in one of the `top.sls` files! I still don't understand why `pillar` goes in `/srv/salt/`, and `salt` goes in `/srv/pillar/`, or even what the difference is between the two. The thing is, the formula doesn't create a `php.sls`, Salt just uses the `srv/salt/php.sls` file instead of the formula, and when the file is deleted, the formula works without it. So, if you have `salt` and `pillar` with the same name, you can only use `salt`.